# Layout file not loaded and routing issue MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

my route config file is

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

by default login is loaded login controller is

```
 [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        ViewBag.CustomerId = 0;
        ViewBag.Country = "pak";
        ViewBag.Email = "nouman@softconsults.com";
        return View();
    }
```

url default load layout page with correct design http://localhost:2738/
but same view with url when click login submit button or called by url 
http://localhost:2738/Login/Login  appears not loaded properly see image for details

[image: issue image]

similar problem with other file my master layout page not loaded but in sign in click my url add login and continue adding incase wrong user password but correct user password work sucess fully and next page only not load its master here url become in case wrong user password that continue adding login

http://localhost:2738/Login/Login/Login/Login

CSS refrence at top

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("Website/CSS/supersized.css")" type="text/css" media="screen " />
<link href="@Url.Content("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700")" rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css'>

<link href="@Url.Content("Website/CSS/custom.css.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("Website/JS/jquery.easing.min.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("Website/JS/supersized.3.2.7.js")"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function ($) {

        $.supersized({

            // Functionality
            slide_interval: 3000,       // Length between transitions
            transition: 3,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed: 700,      // Speed of transition

            // Components
            slide_links: 'blank',   // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
            slides: [           // Slideshow Images
                                                { image: 'Website/Main/banner_1.png', },
                                                { image: 'Website/Main/banner_2.png', },
                                                { image: 'Website/Main/banner_3.png', },
                                                { image: 'Website/Main/banner_4.png', },
                                                { image: 'Website/Main/banner_5.png', },
                                                { image: 'Website/Main/banner_6.png', },
                                                { image: 'Website/Main/banner_7.png', },
                                                { image: 'Website/Main/banner_8.png', }

            ]

        });
    });

</script>
```

At bottom of page login and home index view

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
<script  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js")"></script>
 <script  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
 <script  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
 <script  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: see url in image both color part and not colored

Comment: Both your routes are identical (they accept between 0 and 3 segments) and only the first one will ever be hit

Comment: solution if any what changes i do

Comment: Its just a comment on your route definitions (delete the 2nd one - its pointless), not the answer to your question

Comment: @StephenMuecke Exactly! OP should remove second route definition from route.config

Comment: @NoumanArshad Can you show us your css and js references in page.

Comment: i updated question and removed the route of home too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using direct relative path, try to use below method.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Website/CSS/supersized.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You can use this approach for CSS, JS, Images as well.

Comment: i did it but problem is still same

Comment: Try to see the console, if you find 404 then tell me the path of css url

Comment: my dear friend have added "~" symbol?? in css

Comment: in network tab you can find css tab.. so there you need to check, whether it is loaded or not?

Comment: ` { image:  '@Url.Content("~/Website/Main/banner_1.png")'  , },` resolve design issue

Comment: now url route issue remaining why its adding login again login and increasing

Comment: remove this attribute "[Route("")]"

Comment: i did it but still have

Comment: Show me your form tag.. It should be like this "@using (Html.BeginForm())"... Dont add any action name inside the form tag.

Comment: YES its same as you said `@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)` can you also tell me why when i want to call search it change url calling search controller

Comment: I did't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I am saying that 1st thing when i click button to post data my above url that i have shown changes and continue changing like when i click login but enter wrong detail this result in url  login/login again wrong login/login/login and continue this is my issue and i need help that on click url remain same in case wrong user password in case true sucess navigation take place

Comment: and my every button is doing call back operation infact  only one submit have to do this i handle this using ` onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>'"` but this change URL is there way through routing to handle url change calling another action in same controller or different